# Unit testing CakePHP model find methods

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I was wondering what the general consensus was around testing custom find methods as found in CakePHP models.

Is it worth it or do most people skip it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive answer is: it depends!

You should ask yourself the following questions:
- how often is the code likely to change in future?
- how hard is it to test? How long will writing the test take?
- do you have a history of breaking things when changing the code you're referring to?
- how likely is it that the particular code you're referring to, if broken, will show up as an obvious error in basic manual testing?
- what are the repercussions if it does break? Small? Disastrous?
- how many other people are involved in the project?
- is more of a small, 'set and forget' type of website? Or an app that will require ongoing maintenance?

There's no one simple answer. If you're unsure, err on the side of testing more rather than less, as it will usually pay off. The basic overall formula is: if it takes you eg. 30 mins to write a unit test, then that test has paid for itself once it has saved you 30 mins worth of manual testing, debugging, or other hassle.

If you're new to unit testing, just test everything you think of, just for the experience, until you get a feel for when unit testing is worth it, and when it's overkill.

Oh, and never bother testing stuff that's already tested elsewhere - eg. in the CakePHP core unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing is always worth effort if you plan to support application.